# Is there the possibility to have more than one .ini file per language

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, custom-component, translation

I'm building a component that will be kind of big, and I'd like to separate my internationalization keys into more than one file per language in order to organize them better. Is that possible in Joomla 3.4?

Comment: By default, I don't think so, however I'd suggest using 1 file per language anyway. It will result in fewer HTTP requests, thus improving performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually load the language files, you could do it.  But Joomla itself won't automatically support this, and truthfully there is no benefit to it beyond personal preference (the code that loads and parses the INI files is already pretty well optimized with Joomla 3.5 is getting some additional performance enhancements).